# Can't get password authentication to work

Tags: postgresql

I want to do something very simple: create a PostgreSQL database and then connect to it using `psql`. So here's what I did:

1. `sudo apt install postgresql-9.6` (on Ubuntu 18.04)
2. `sudo -su postgres` (start a shell for the postgres system user)
3. `createuser -P foo` (create a user and prompt for a password for that user)
4. `createdb -O foo foo` (create a database owned by the previously created user)

All this worked flawlessly, no errors anywhere. And yet, when I try to connect to the database using `psql -h localhost -U foo foo`, I can't access the database (the password is definitely correct). The error message is `psql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "foo"`

`/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_hba.conf` looks as follows:

```
local   all          postgres                   peer
local   all          all                        peer
host    all          all        127.0.0.1/32    md5
host    all          all        ::1/128         md5
```

It all looks fine to me, yet it just doesn't work. What am I missing here?

I have also tried `alter user foo valid until 'infinity'`. And while the command completed successfully, it didn't help with the problem.

// edit: I noticed something strange about this problem. When I remove the `-h localhost`, peer authentication fails (as expected, because there is no user `foo` on the system). This leaves three lines of logs in `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log`. However when I do use the `-h localhost` flag, no logs are generated at all.

//edit: I have now tried the same thing on a Fedora 28 machine and it works as expected. I have no idea what the difference might be (other than the operating system and postgres version (10.5)

Comment: you have to use -W <password> in order for the password to work

Comment: The man page says about -W that “this option is never essential”. And psql does prompt for a password, it just doesn't accept it.

Comment: pg_hba.conf is correct, the message points to an incorrect password. Maybe you made an error when setting foo's password. Try giving foo a new password.

Comment: I have repeated this process several times. I am absolutely sure the password is correct.

Comment: Just noticed you are using -s in your psql command which should be -h `psql -h localhost -U foo foo` (though on my setup that is giving completely different errors)

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I was in fact using -h.

Comment: Can you connect when you change md5 in the pg_hba.conf to trust?

Comment: I've made that change and restarted postgresql (using `systemctl restart postgresql`), but I still can't log in. I also started `psql` as the `postgres` system user (so host authentication seems to work) and used `show hba_file` to show which `pg_hba.conf` is being used. But it is the right one, `/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_hba.conf`. I'm completely baffled by this behaviour at this point…

Comment: Any environment variables set that start with `PG`? Try using `lsof` on the `psql` process to see if it is connected to `localhost`. Did you reload or restart PostgreSQL after changing configuration files? What if you set the password with `ALTER ROLE foo PASSWORD '...';` as user `postgres`?

Comment: I didn't set any non-default environment variables. I have have used wireshark to look at the traffic and it goes from 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.0.1. As mentioned before, I have also restarted Postgresql after changing the configuration file. Setting the password in this other way didn't help either. Thanks for trying to help though. But at this point, I'll probably just nuke the Ubuntu installation and go ahead with Fedora. It's a stupid solution, but I don't know what else to do and it works on Fedora.